# DocumentDb -> Is Index a reserved word?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I have a documentDb instance which I can query using the azure portal tools:
[image]

When I write the same query in code like this:

```
let valuationCollection = client.CreateDocumentCollectionQuery(database.CollectionsLink).Where(fun dc -> dc.Id = "taxinformation").ToArray().FirstOrDefault()
let valuationDocumentLink = valuationCollection.SelfLink
let valuationQueryString = "SELECT * FROM ti WHERE ti.index = 1"
let valuationQuery = client.CreateDocumentQuery(valuationQueryString,valuationQueryString)
let valuationValue = valuationQuery |> Seq.head
let valuation = HouseValuation.Parse(valuationValue.ToString())
```

I am getting this error:

> System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. --->
>   Microsoft.Azure.Documents.NotFoundException: The value 'SELECT * FROM
>   TI WHERE TI.INDEX = 1' specified  for query '$resolveFor' is invalid. 
>   at
>   Microsoft.Azure.Documents.BackoffRetryUtility`1.d__0.MoveNext()

I have other queries that work fine.  I am wondering if "index" should not be used?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, index is not reserved. You should be able to use this.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with the code itself on line 4 above:

```
let valuationQuery = client.CreateDocumentQuery(valuationQueryString,valuationQueryString)
```

should be

```
let valuationQuery = client.CreateDocumentQuery(valuationDocumentLink,valuationQueryString)
```